# Android TV box WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-tv

I've got a small application that display stream from server to webView. I've installed it to my phone and it works properly, but when i compile it on tv box my WebView doesn't displayed.I've install android WebView from google play but it doesn't help.

Android TV box x96.

Just in case my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String url = "https://www.google.com.ua";

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wevView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

Xml

```
<WebView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/wevView">
```

Comment: btw anroid version on tv box is 6.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Make sure you added permission for using Internet in your Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Secondly , Add this code before `webView.loadUrl(url);` :

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: It doesn't help. It works properly on Android Tv Emulator and on my phone.But when I install apk on tv box WebView doesn't display.

Comment: try to use another site url.

Comment: Maybe you know who compile that component. It compiled by built-in browser or Android sdk?